# Not able to merge records in Oracle database using merge statement

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-merge

```
SELECT * FROM DIM_TRANS_TYPE WHERE TRANSACTION_TYPE='ILAU';
```

[image]

All I want to accomplish here is change `ILAU` to `IFAU` and `Instant Loan Authorization Request` to `Instant Finance Authorization Request` in the above-mentioned record.

**Table Schema:**

```
Name                  Null     Type               
--------------------- -------- ------------------ 
TRANSACTION_TYPE      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(4 CHAR)   --> PRIMARY KEY
TRANSACTION_TYPE_DESC          VARCHAR2(256 CHAR)
```

**WORKS !!!**

```
MERGE INTO DIM_TRANS_TYPE a
USING (SELECT 'ILAU' TRANSACTION_TYPE, 'Instant Loan Authorization Request' TRANSACTION_TYPE_DESC FROM DUAL) b
    ON (a.TRANSACTION_TYPE = b.TRANSACTION_TYPE)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET
      a.TRANSACTION_TYPE_DESC = 'Instant Finance Authorization Request'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT(a.TRANSACTION_TYPE, a.TRANSACTION_TYPE_DESC)
    VALUES(b.TRANSACTION_TYPE, b.TRANSACTION_TYPE_DESC);
```

**DOES NOT WORK !!! (Error shown below)**

```
MERGE INTO DIM_TRANS_TYPE a
USING (SELECT 'ILAU' TRANSACTION_TYPE, 'Instant Loan Authorization Request' TRANSACTION_TYPE_DESC FROM DUAL) b
    ON (a.TRANSACTION_TYPE = b.TRANSACTION_TYPE)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET
      a.TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'IFAU',
      a.TRANSACTION_TYPE_DESC = 'Instant Finance Authorization Request'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT(a.TRANSACTION_TYPE, a.TRANSACTION_TYPE_DESC)
    VALUES(b.TRANSACTION_TYPE, b.TRANSACTION_TYPE_DESC);
```

**Error:**

```
Error at Command Line : 5 Column : 9
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: "A"."TRANSACTION_TYPE"
38104. 00000 -  "Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: %s"
*Cause:    LHS of UPDATE SET contains the columns referenced in the ON Clause
*Action:
```

Comment: can you please post the schema for DIM_TRANS_TYPE

Comment: Just updated the above post with table schema

Comment: the error message is clear and it is one of the restrictions of `merge` that you can't update the columns being referenced in `on`. check the documenation https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606

Comment: The error seems pretty straightforward, you can't update the column matching in the ON clause (a.TRANSACTION_TYPE). Can you insert into a new table then update your original table so they aren't the same column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message indicates, it is not possible to update the fields that are used in the `on` clause.

You'll have to do this kind of update in a separate statement. Something like this:

```
UPDATE DIM_TRANS_TYPE
SET    TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'IFAU',
       TRANSACTION_TYPE_DESC = 'Instant Finance Authorization Request'
WHERE  TRANSACTION_TYPE IN (
            SELECT TRANSATION_TYPE
            FROM   (SELECT 'ILAU' TRANSACTION_TYPE, 
                           'Instant Loan Authorization Request' TRANSACTION_TYPE_DESC 
                    FROM DUAL)
       );

MERGE INTO DIM_TRANS_TYPE a
USING      (SELECT 'ILAU' TRANSACTION_TYPE, 
                   'Instant Loan Authorization Request' TRANSACTION_TYPE_DESC 
            FROM   DUAL) b
        ON (a.TRANSACTION_TYPE = b.TRANSACTION_TYPE)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT(TRANSACTION_TYPE, TRANSACTION_TYPE_DESC)
    VALUES(b.TRANSACTION_TYPE, b.TRANSACTION_TYPE_DESC);
```

You may want to execute this in a transaction, so that the changes incurred by either both or neither of these statements are committed.

Of course, the `IN` clause looks a bit exaggerated as the value could simply be compared with `ILAU`, but I assume you simplified the question when in reality you have a bigger dataset to get the `transaction_type` values from.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am missing something....   It seems you are looking to identify all the rows where `transaction_type = 'ILAU'` (**regardless** of `transaction_type_desc`), and for those rows to update `transaction_type` to `'IFAU'` and `transaction_type_desc` to `'Instant Finance Authorization Request'`. Right?

If so, why do you need anything other than a trivial `UPDATE` statement?

```
update  dim_trans_type
  set   transaction_type      = 'IFAU',
        transaction_type_desc = 'Instant Finance Authorization Request'
  where transaction_type      = 'ILAU'
;
```

In your attempts there is also a `when not matched` clause - inserting a row if none of the existing rows have `transaction_type = 'ILAU'`. How is that related to your requirement? You said **All I want to accomplish here is change [.....]** - no mention of inserting anything. Is the problem statement, in plain English, incomplete? Or are you inserting things that don't need to be inserted?